# How to create paragraphs that function as filters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering how to make this code much simpler and shorter.
I have three paragraphs in HTML which are used as filters.
Their IDs, respectively, are "all", "positive" and "negative".
They are referring to reviews.
Underneath them are three divs which will contain actual reviews.
They also carry IDs with names "allcont", "poscont" and "negcont", respectively.
The idea here is when I click on "all" paragraph only the "allcont" div should show up without "postcont" and "negcont".
The same goes for "positive" paragraph and "negative" paragraph.

This way I would create three filter buttons which show different reviews.

Here is the code:

```
var allcont = document.getElementById("allcont");
var poscont = document.getElementById("poscont");
var negcont = document.getElementById("negcont");
var all = document.getElementById("all");
var positive = document.getElementById("positive");
var negative = document.getElementById("negative");
all.onclick = function(){
    allcont.style.display = "block";
    poscont.style.display = "none";
    negcont.style.display = "none";
    all.style.color = "red";
    positive.style.color = "white";
    negative.style.color = "white";
}
positive.onclick = function(){
    poscont.style.display = "block";
    allcont.style.display = "none";
    negcont.style.display = "none";
    positive.style.color = "red";
    all.style.color = "white";
    negative.style.color = "white";  
}
negative.onclick = function(){
    negcont.style.display = "block";
    poscont.style.display = "none";
    allcont.style.display = "none";
    negative.style.color = "red";
    all.style.color = "white";
    positive.style.color = "white";
}
```

When any of the paragraphs is clicked it should change the color to red as I wrote in the code above.

This works but looks very ugly and complicated and I'm sure it can be done a lot easier using a for loop or something similar.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Comment: Provide a working code sample, not only a script fragment

Answer (score 1):

I hate recommending jQuery, but with jQuery, it will become simpler.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".pfilter").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".cont").hide();
    $("#"+$this.data("show")).show();
    $(".pfilter").css("color", "blue");
    $this.css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: blue;
}

div.cont {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="all" data-show="allcont" class="pfilter">ALL</p>
<p id="positive" data-show="poscont" class="pfilter">POSITIVE</p>
<p id="negative" data-show="negcont" class="pfilter">NEGATIVE</p>
<hr>
<div id="allcont" class="cont">ALLCONT DIV</div>
<div id="poscont" class="cont">POSTCONT DIV</div>
<div id="negcont" class="cont">NEGCONT DIV</div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Only change I'd suggest is to move styling out of the onclick handler and into css classes: `$(this).addClass('selected'); $("#"+$this.data('show')).addClass('selected')`.